# Moving latte-dock to another display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde5, latte-dock

How to move latte-dock to another display?
`Latte-settings->Behavior->Location->Screen` has only `On Primary` option and doesn't recognize my secondary screen.

Latte : 0.7.4

OS : Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Right click on Latte dock -> Behavior -> Screen (drop down options).
In my case, there is a "DP-1" and "DP-2".